# How to toggle actions(changes in view) with buttons in ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have tried to google many different ways that could translate to what I what but I'm afraid that I might be using the wrong keywords. I have posted a question prior to this but it got down voted and I presume its because I wasnt specific enough. So here goes, what I basically want to do is to render a form for a `paperclip img` on top of an existing image that was already uploaded if a button is clicked. In my case it will say `edit profile`. Below is a screenshot of what I currently have.

[image]

This would also render a form for the business name (on the bottom left) in place of the current name of the business. What I have in mind that I need to do is to have `if` statements all around my page that checks for a `boolean` variable. If button is clicked, show all the `forms` in place of their actual attribute. The only problem I have right now is how to check for this said variable and how to assign it to a click. Im not even sure if this is the right way to do this and if someone else could shed some light on this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: did you try jquery click event ?

Comment: ill go check that out thanks! I have not heard of it before, the reason its on the tag is because it showed up as one of the options

Comment: @EdwardLim I think you can have multiple partials here. If user hits `Edit Profile`  that should set an instance variable in  your controller's action and based upon the value of that instance variable, you can render different partials. Like you can have a partial which shows the current page with simple attributes and you can have another partial with forms.

Comment: I see what you mean! Thank you, Ill keep that in mind while i do some research on jquery

Comment: show  your partial view onclick event